# Perl - Connect to PostgreSQL Database - Failing to find proper socket

Tags: perl, postgresql, connect, dbi

I can connect fine with PHP and locally using Psql, but Perl does not.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=mydb,host=localhost:5432","user","pass",{'RaiseError' => 1});
```

I believe the error is because my socket is in tmp:

```
postgres@host/opt/psql/bin $ netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24728255 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24729004 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

And when I run my simple perl script it seems to look in /var/run:

```
./test.pl
DBI connect('dbname=mydb','user',...) failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? at ./test.pl line 6
```

I tried to simply create a symlink, but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432': No such file or directory
```

Some other simple stuff:
pg_hba.conf trusts all localhost connections as well as those of my subnet.

postgresql.conf has the following:
    listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. That should cause it to use TCP instead of a UNIX socket.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-HOST:

> host
>
> Name of host to connect to. If this begins with a slash, it specifies
>   Unix-domain communication rather than TCP/IP communication; the value
>   is the name of the directory in which the socket file is stored. The
>   default behavior when host is not specified is to connect to a
>   Unix-domain socket in /tmp (or whatever socket directory was specified
>   when PostgreSQL was built). On machines without Unix-domain sockets,
>   the default is to connect to localhost.

So a connection string that has `host=/tmp` should make your Pg client look in the right place (which is supposed to be the default anyway).

Comment: That's it - I had tried to use the full path to the socket (/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432) but that did not work.  Using just /tmp does.

Comment: Removing the `host` parameter will help, too.